# A word for "Doing the correct thing for the wrong reason" when you know the correct reason but are motivated by the wrong one

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I was given a description and example of a word in high school and have always remembered the description and example but not the word.

The example given was "Wearing a helmet when riding a bike because you don't want to get fined by the police rather than because it's safer to wear a helmet".

There are similar questions on here but I believe they have the assumption that the subject is unaware that they are doing it for the wrong reason. In this instance, the subject knows that it's better for their safety to wear a helmet, but their actual motivation is to avoid getting a fine.

Comment: I don't think there's necessarily any deception involved. In the helmet example, I don't think there's any need to hide your motivation, it's just that your motivation is monetary rather than safety. I guess you could debate what the "right" reason is, but the reason for the fine is to coerce people into wearing helmets because it is safer. It comes down to external vs internal motivation I suppose.